Why does Instagram Stories throw an error when sharing an image via UIActivityViewController?
I am using UIActivityViewController to share an image to Instagram and other platforms. Here’s the code snippet I am using:
let image = UIImage(named: "sample_image")!
let activity = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [image], applicationActivities: nil)
present(activity, animated: true, completion: nil)

When I select Instagram from the share menu, a submenu appears with three options: Post, Story, and Message. Selecting Story consistently causes an error, while Post and Message work as expected.
I’ve attached a screenshot of the error that appears when selecting Story.

Additional Notes:

I’ve noticed that similar share operations from apps like Photos and Line (with identical UI flow and steps) can share images to Instagram Stories without any issue.
The image is a standard UIImage loaded from the app's asset catalog.
Instagram is installed and updated to the latest version on the
device.

Question:
Is there a specific requirement for sharing to Instagram Stories through UIActivityViewController that I might be missing? How can I resolve this issue?

A shot in the dark: try sharing a URL of the image instead of a UIImage.

Are you authorized to share an image with istagram? How are you getting the image? what format is the image? Are you using the correct API key? where do post and message go? Can you share some of the code that interacts with sending the image without showing your API key?

@user20325868 I’m using UIActivityViewController, not any Instagram-specific APIs, with a standard .png image; "Post" and "Message" work, but "Story" throws an error—the code in my question is all I’m using; is there a better approach?

@Sweeper Genius! It works.
